# Ag-grid number filter for decimals (bug?)

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

i'm using
ag-grid-community 19.1.4
ag-grid-enterprise 19.1.4
ag-grid-react 19.1.2

im using a `valueGetter` to format numbers with long decimal values to shorter ones with `toFixed` -- for example 123.12345 to 123.12

however filtering seems to not work properly anymore on those values, as in filtering works but only until i enter 2nd decimal -- using example above:
filter works if i enter 123.1 (shows the row)
filter hides the row if i type in 123.12

Is there a limitation on this feature, or is it a bug that is fixed in later versions of ag-grid modules? or is there a workaround to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ok turns out valueGetter was returning strings instead of numbers, so filtering didnt work properly. Had to use Number() to return proper type.